# applying styles w/ jquery in IE9 w/ vendor prefixes?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-9

I noticed that adding in styles w/ jQuery in IE9 works fine however this just doesn't seem to work:

```
box.css({'-ms-transform': 'scale(.2)'});
```

although when I try to do that w/ any other vendor prefix -webkit-/-moz-/etc it works fine... does it need to be applied differently for IE? (the scale is dynamic hence the reason i'm doing it in js and not in css)

Comment: Check-out my **updated** answer, IE9 does not support `-ms-transform : scale()`.

Comment: @Jasper check my answer's test page, IE9 supports -ms-transform:scale()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just checked it on the last few versions of jQuery and it seems to be working fine there must be some other issue with your code.  did you check to make sure box.length > 0 ?

here's the test page: http://jsbin.com/ehasuz/edit#javascript,live

hope this helps -ck

**edit: just cause i feel like we are not all on the same page with the demo**
[image: -ms-transform:scale on ie9]

this would make me hazard a guess that your problem is somewhere else, unless there is a case where ie9 optionally applies css3 transforms..

hope this helps -ck

Comment: well see the crazy thing is that I've tried to apply other styles as a test like changing the background color and all that stuff and everything works except for this -ms-transform... starting to get really irritated with it...

Comment: the test page I created shows it working in IE9... the syntax provided here is the correct one...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your exact issue but you could try:

```
box[0].style.MsTransform = 'scale(0.2)';
```

If `box` holds more than one element then you would have to loop through them for this to work:

```
for (var i = 0, len = box.length; i < len; i++) {
    box[i].style.MsTransform = 'scale(0.2)';
}
```

Comment: yes, you are correct **IE** does not support **-webkit-transform:scale()** mainly because IE does not use *webkit*